# Unable to connect to AWS RDS instance?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, firewall

I have set up a AWS RDS instance and am using the "end point" as hostname to establish the connection via MySQL workbench, but the connection is failing.

I am sitting behind a company firewall and as per [online tools](http://www.canyouseeme.org/), port 3306, the port that I am using for the connection is closed.

Can this be the reason why I am not being able to connect?

Comment: Why don't you switch off the firewall temporarily to test this?

Comment: What are your security group settings on the RDS?